# How to mock angularJS service with $resource that has custom action?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
From the API of $resource we know that there is a custom action in $resource method that can be called. My question is, how to mock a service that has this custom action?

For example the BaseService code is like this:

```
angular.module('shared').factory('BaseService', function($resource) {
    var resourceConfig = {
        serverBaseUrl: AJAXConfig.ajaxUrl+"&resource_id="
    };

    var createResource = function(url, paramDefaults, actions) {
        return $resource(resourceConfig.serverBaseUrl + url, 
            paramDefaults, actions);
    };

    return {
        createResource: createResource
    };
});
```

Another TopService that depends on BaseService is like:

```
angular.module('SomeModule').factory('TopService', 
    function($resource, BaseService) {

    var listResource = BaseService.createResource('onSomeList', 
        null, {
            getList: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
            }
        });

    var getSomeList = function() {
        return listResource.getList().$promise;
    };

    return { getSomeList : getSomeList };
}
```

Now I need to write the unit test code for TopService, so I mock BaseService using $provide:

```
module(function($provide) {
    $provide.service('BaseService', function($q) {
        ....
    }
}
```

I can mock createResource method using
    jasmine.createSpy('createResource').and.callFake(...)
but how can I mock the custom action getList()?

Update: I realized that listResource can be simplified to:

```
        var listResource = BaseService.createResource('onSomeList', 
        null, {
            get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
            }
        });
```

So the custom action has a standard name "get", but I still don't know how to mock it in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

i'd do this way

```
var getListMock = jasmine.createSpy();
module(function($provide) {
    $provide.service('BaseService', function($q) {
        return {
                createResource:jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(getListMock)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock the resource. You need to mock the service. Instead of creating `shared` at the top of your test, create `YourMocks`.

YourMocks can look like this:

```
angular.module('YourMocks, [])
.factory('TopService', function($q) {
   return {getSomeList: function(){$q.when('your test data goes here')};
});
```

Comment: But this would make the TopService code not covered, right? I know I can mock at higher level, but this test code is trying to cover as many lines of code for TopService as possible, so I have to use real TopService and mock BaseService.

Comment: If you want to cover the TopService code, then you need to look at the docs for using the [$http mock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). I tend to not bother with testing services that are mostly just calling methods on angular's own code (which is itself extensively tested).

Comment: It's actually not clear why you are adding another layer on top of a service that already just calls $resource. It seems like a waste of time.